# how do i allow space in regex in mod_rewrite engine

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

i have a regex that i want it to allow white spaces. this regex i am using is in the .htaccess file. whenever i put the `\s` it makes the whole regex not work

what can i do to make it allow white spaces and work?

this is my regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$

RewriteRule ^(?!profile|home|recieved|search|ajaxsearch|sent|favorites|deletemessage|favorite|replypopup|deletereply|Editprofile|changepass|followingsystem|checkFollowers|block|report|logout|login|register|forgotpassword|resetpassword|twitterapi|index|manage)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$ ./searchusers.php?search=$1 [L]
```

this is my full rewrite rule, when i put \s it doesn't work

Comment: `\s` does work fine, Can you show your full .htaccess and clarify requirement

Comment: check my edited question please @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!profile|home|recieved|search|ajaxsearch|sent|favorites|deletemessage|favorite|replypopup|deletereply|Editprofile|changepass|followingsystem|checkFollowers|block|report|logout|login|register|forgotpassword|resetpassword|twitterapi|index|manage)([^/]+)/?$ ./searchusers.php?search=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Here `[^/]` is negated character class that matches any character except `/` and it will match whitespace as well.